# Why can't I connect to any Minecraft servers with Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

Okay, so for the past few weeks, I've had a problem with Minecraft. The problem is that when I play on a new server, I log in and everything is fine, but after about 4 or 5 minutes playing, the game kicks me from the server and I can't reconnect.

In the server list, it says "Can't reach server" and when I try connecting to any server, the connection times out. I even asked my friend that has a server to look at the console of his server, and when I got kicked, it says connection lost, generic.reason. And when I try connecting to the server, my connection attempt doesn't even show up. Help!

Comment: Are you trying to host a server?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or Oracle Java? OpenJDK doesn't always work as well as Oracle as it is not the "official" version of java.

Also have you tried to force update your minecraft, and make sure you're not using any mods?

Comment: Nova, I am not trying to host a minecraft server, it is me connecting to the servers. And I'm pretty sure i'm running the "official" Java runtime.

Answer (score 1):

hard to say if you didn't provide more details (versions, mods, etc.), but most often this is client problem rather than server. Please try to backup your MC binnaries and download them again (you should enable "Force Update" option before login or simply delete these files, maybe 2nd is better). While you'll be playing please press F3 and watch memory usage (all the time until the crash).

Comment: I have no mod's installed, but i can't tell you what type of Ubuntu I'm running at the moment. I'll try force updating and re-installing my .bin of minecraft. And it's not a crash, the game simply disconnects me from the server. Also, i know it's not a server issue, because no-one before has had that issue. And i don't think i would run out of memory, because i have 8gbs installed ;p

Comment: @Alek How much memory you have installed is not the same to how much memory is allocated to java. The default is 1GB, which can be problematic with high-resolution texture packs or other mods installed.

Answer (score 1):

Update your java too; some minecraft issues are related to buggy java libraries.